# Make a flex container scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with this styles:

```css
section {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

this section has some children ( say like two divs with #one and #two id ). when i set their height to `height: 100%;` i expect them to make the section scroll( because 2*100% = 200%, right? ). but instead they just overflow the section. how do i achieve this ?

To be more specific, in the following HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="root">
<section>
    <div id="one">Hi im div 1!</div>
    <div id="two">Hi im div 2!</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div id="three">Hi im div 3!</div>
</section>
</div>
</body>
```

and the following css for body and `div#root`:

```css
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#root{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
#one, #two{
height : 100%;
}
```

I want the first section to be scrollable, and the second one to exactly fit the viewport. its clear that the `div#root` will be scrollable too.

Comment: Add the relevant HTML.

Comment: you can use overflow auto

Comment: @Sarout on which element?

Comment: the section, but scroll already working on your example, but when it's no need to scroll, you can't, try to set the height to a smaller thing to understand what's happening

Comment: @Sarout sorry i dont understand :D , could you show a code example?

Comment: yeah of course I can but my point is why scroll when all content is already shown on the screen, it doesn't make sense, anyway I'm doing an example

Answer (score 0):

As your description, I created the sample scenario and it's working. or am i missing something ?

```css
body{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#root{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sec1{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#one{
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
<section class="sec1">
    <div id="one">Hi im div 1!</div>
    <div id="two">Hi im div 2!</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div id="three">Hi im div 3!</div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: its the full page scrolling, not just the section, i'll update the question with a more specific HTML

Comment: Yah that would be more specific.

Comment: 100% height is a relative property. I changed the snippet using px.

Comment: Well your not applying `display: flex;` to the section element

Comment: I added `display: flex;` its still scrollable but when you apply `flex-direction: column` its no more scrollable

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jxLmq7u/ 
see this , its scrollable but #one is off the view and section totally

Answer (score 0):

you have to make the section shorter, so its content don't have enough place to fit, then the overflow set the scroll automatically

so

```css
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 25vh; //<-- 
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: auto;/*<-- scroll forces all sections to have handler and this is not recommended in you example*/
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body {
  width: 100%; /* <-- just to show you the scrollbar */
  height: 100vh;
  /* overflow-x: hidden;<-- no need */
  /* overflow-y: scroll;<-- no need */
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#root {
  width: 90%; /* <-- just to show you the scrollbar */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#one,
#two {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <section>
    <div id="one">Hi im div 1!</div>
    <div id="two">Hi im div 2!</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div id="three">Hi im div 3!</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) if you don't have any idea about overflow.

Answer (score 0):

While [Saurot's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922244/6515840) was very helpful, i found that the solution was setting `flex: 0 0 100%` for child divs. thanks everyone! :D